# Control Output Within PHP While Loop

Tags: php

I have a while loop that a query is in and the MySQL query works just fine. However when I try to output my text saying that the query is successful I get:

"Table Succesfully UpdatedTable Succesfully UpdatedTable Succesfully Updated"

I know this I happening becuase I am editing 3 objects, so I'm wondering is there a way to output the string without having it repeat however many objects I change?

Here is the loop:

```
while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) 
{
    $part_num = $r3['part_num'];
    $desc = $r3['desc'];
    $bom_qty = $r3['qty'];
    $need_qty = $qty * $bom_qty;
    //insert the part_num into the temp parts table and the qty
    $resut4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty')");
    if ($resut4) {
        echo 'Table Succesfully Updated';
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all... I think these updates should go in a transaction. Now if you don't want a transaction. Then just take a boolean and keep on ANDing it with each query success. Print according to this boolean.

Comment: About tansactions - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-transactions.htm,Transactions in php - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-transaction/

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql

Comment: Hi i have updated my answer and posted a more optimized way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
$part_num = $r3['part_num']; $desc = $r3['desc']; $bom_qty = $r3['qty']; $need_qty = $qty*$bom_qty;
   //insert the part_num into the temp parts table and the qty
$resut4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty')");
    if ( $resut4 ) {
        $error = false;
    } else {
            $error = true;
            echo mysql_error();
    }
}
if(!$error) {
   echo "table successful updated"
}
```

Untested, but should work fine.

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql.

Comment: @sgt i use AdoDB, but if he is using mysql, I'll give the sample code for mysql, everything else would be not helpful and offtopic. He asked for help because of the echo, not because of the mysql.

Comment: @JoeyFeilmeier Glad that i could help! :) Feel free to mark this as accepted answer so other people might find it helpful too.

Comment: @sgt you should tell him then, not me. Post the comment below the question, not below one of the answers.

Comment: better to have this message on stackoverflow whenever its related to mqsql.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $bool =false;
    while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
        $part_num = $r3['part_num']; $desc = $r3['desc']; $bom_qty = $r3['qty']; $need_qty = $qty*$bom_qty;
           //insert the part_num into the temp parts table and the qty
        $resut4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty')");
            if ( $resut4 && $bool==false) {
                echo 'Table Succesfully Updated';
              $bool=true;
            } else if(!$result) {
                    echo mysql_error();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$check=true;
while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
$part_num = $r3['part_num']; $desc = $r3['desc']; $bom_qty = $r3['qty']; $need_qty = $qty*$bom_qty;   
$resut4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty')");
    if (!$resut4 ) {
      $check=false;
      echo mysql_error();
    }
}
if($check)
{
echo "table successful updated";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The more optimized way to do this is create the query in the loop and fire it once and not inside the loop again and again.

This way you can reduce the load and the execution will be fast

```
<?php
$update_count = 0;
$query_part = "INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ";
while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) 
{
    $part_num = $r3['part_num'];
    $desc = $r3['desc'];
    $bom_qty = $r3['qty'];
    $need_qty = $qty * $bom_qty;
    //create the query part here in the loop 
    $query_part .= "('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty'),";
}

$query_final = substr($query_part, 0,-1);//remove the extra comma at the end
$resut4 = mysql_query($query_final);
if ($resut4) 
{
    echo 'Table(s) Succesfully Updated';
} 
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Below is the answer with your approach

You can print the message one time at the end with the exact count with the below code

```
<?php
$update_count = 0;
while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) 
{
    $part_num = $r3['part_num'];
    $desc = $r3['desc'];
    $bom_qty = $r3['qty'];
    $need_qty = $qty * $bom_qty;
    //insert the part_num into the temp parts table and the qty
    $resut4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty')");
    if ($resut4) 
    {
        $update_count++;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
echo $update_count.' Table(s) Succesfully Updated';
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Put if-else part outside the while loop.

```
  while ($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
      $part_num = $r3['part_num']; $desc = $r3['desc']; $bom_qty = $r3['qty']; $need_qty = $qty*$bom_qty;
      //insert the part_num into the temp parts table and the qty
      $resut4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp_grabtec_parts`(`temp_id`,`part_num`,`desc`,`qty`) VALUES ('$temp_id','$part_num','$desc','$need_qty')") or die(mysql_error());
       }
      if ( $resut4 ) {
      echo 'Table Succesfully Updated';
      } else {
      echo 'Table Update Fail';
      }
```

Comment: What if one of them fails??

Comment: If he will put the condition outside the loop the condition will only check the result for the last query in the loop as the variable $result4 will be over written on each loop iteration and by this way he will not get the perfect result

Comment: If you are posting an answer you should post it completely and should not post a part in the comment